# the version of ubuntu and ros

Tags: ros, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a table.It means that the version of ROS must be matched with ubuntu like the table. And I don't know weather it is right, or not.

```
2016.3  ROS Kinetic Kame        Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) / Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily)
2015.3  ROS Jade Turtle         Ubuntu 15.04 (Wily) / Ubuntu LTS 14.04 (Trusty)
2014.7  ROS Indigo Igloo        Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)
2013.9  ROS Hydro Medusa        Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Prec
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280245/the-version-of-ubuntu-and-ros/) by [albert huang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33350/albert-huang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) should contain the information you are looking for.

Your table is correct, although note that `15.10` and `15.04` are EOL.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0